# Parameters of environment created with openAI gym not getting updated on manual update

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, python-3.6, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to create an openAI gym environment for a four room gridworld to implement SMDP options framework. I have multiple gridmap files that have 0 for possible states and 1 for walls. I am initiating the environment with "None" parameter passed for the mapFile(self.mapFile = None). Then I am manually trying to put a parameter name for mapFile by calling 
    env.mapFile = 'map1.txt'
On resetting the environment, it sets the position of the gridworld as per the gridmap.

```py
def __init__(self, terminal_reward = 1, move_reward = 0):
   self.mapFile = None
```

(initialization of the environment)
Then

```py
env.mapFile = 'map1.txt'
```

Then

```
env.reset()
```

Which load the map and sets all the values inside the grid. But even after manual entry of env.mapFile, it returns an error saying mapFile is a none object. Can someone please help me to get around with this?[image: GridMap text file looks like this]

Adding one more thing - Many of my environment parameters are non editable because of some reason and mapFile is one of them